# Installing the .NET 6 SDK deletes Discord, how to keep both and why does it happen?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

Someone else seems to have had my exact same issue, but they deleted their question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424247/latest-dotnet6-sdk-installation-will-delete-discord-and-libc1, so here I am making my own post.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, and have Discord installed with the deb file they provided on their site. If I try installing the .NET 6 SDK with `sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0`, this is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-6.0 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-6.0 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0
  dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-6.0 dotnet-runtime-6.0 dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0
  dotnet-templates-6.0 liblttng-ust-common1 liblttng-ust-ctl5 liblttng-ust1
  libunwind-13 netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  discord libc++1 libc++1-14 libc++abi1-14 libunwind-14
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aspnetcore-runtime-6.0 aspnetcore-targeting-pack-6.0 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0
  dotnet-host dotnet-hostfxr-6.0 dotnet-runtime-6.0 dotnet-sdk-6.0
  dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0 dotnet-templates-6.0 liblttng-ust-common1
  liblttng-ust-ctl5 liblttng-ust1 libunwind-13 netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 82,8 MB/124 MB of archives.
After this operation, 264 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

Why does it want to delete Discord and those other packages, and how can I keep Discord when installing the .NET 6 SDK?

Comment: My guess would be that the package you are installing has `libunwind-13` as a dependency, which conflicts with the `libunwind-14` that your version of `discord` depends on.

Comment: @zwets That would make sense. Is it possible to install both of these two versions of libunwind so that I can install both applications without conflicts?

Comment: FYI, this is related to the fixed bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dotnet6/+bug/1984450, included from the latest released version of the dotnet6 package (6.0.109).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord currently relies on libunwind-14 while dotnet6 relies on libunwind-13.

**Solution 1:**

With [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) you can install both and avoid the versioning conflict.

Install Snap:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Install dotnet 6 SDK:

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic --channel=6.0
```

Validate install dotnet SDK's

```
dotnet --list-sdk
```

Maybe you need to set an alias:

```
sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet
```

You can find more information about dotnet with snap at the [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap).

**Solution 2: Microsoft Package**

The package directly offered by Microsoft does not include the reference on libunwind.

You can find instructions at the [Microsoft Docs for manual dotnet installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the second solution, since I prefer not to use snap.

Comment: Your first link appears to be in German.

Comment: @J.Mini updated, thanks.